# Azure Search: Keyword tokenizer don't work with multi word search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a fields in index with `[Analyzer(<name>)]` applied. This analyzer is of type `CustomAnalyzer` with `tokenizer = Keyword`. I assume it treats both field value and search text as one term each. E.g. 
ClientName = My Test Client (in index, is broken into 1 term). Search term = My Test Client (broken in 1 term). Result = match.

But surprisingly that's not the case until I apply phrasal search (enclose term in double quotes). Does anyone know why? And how to solve it? I'd rather treat search term as the whole, then do enclosing

Regards,
Sergei.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Query text is processed first by the query parser and only individual query terms go through lexical analysis. When you issue a phrase query, the whole expression between quotes is treated as a phrase term and as one goes through lexical analysis. You can find a complete explanation of this process here: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).